# How to link a File.framework file using linker flags in XCode?

Tags: c++, xcode, linker

I have a File.framework file and wish to link it against my project by using the Other Linker Flags section of the build. Its under build settings, Other Linker Flags.

Typically it has -framework Cocoa type entries, but I have a framework file I want to reference. How can I link the framework file?

Comment: What do you mean by link the framework file: link the framework, import a header file, or access some other file inside the framework? In Xcode you normally link to frameworks instead of linking to a file in a framework. To link a framework, add it to the target's Link Binary with Libraries build phase. If you're trying to access a file inside a framework, I can't help you.

Comment: Assuming `File.framework` isn't just a plain file but actually a framework, `-framework File.framework` should do the job. You will have to adjust the `Framework Search Path` build setting, i.e., add the path to your framework to it. I can't really test this at the moment because I don't have a non-Apple framework at hand...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following.

Add the following in **Other Linker Flags**

```
-framework <Framework Name>  // avoid extension .Framework, just the name.
```

In your case it will be

```
- framework File
```

Then add appropriate path to your framework in **Library Search Paths**

**example:-**

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)/FOLDER_REFER_TO_FILE.FRAMEWORK
```

According to your need you can add it for ***Debug*** and ***Release*** configurations separately. It will work.

I have tried it with Xcode 9.2.

Comment: this helps a lot